# .Net LINQ - Filter a dictionary using another dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two dictionaries of the same type, A and B.

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>
```

I'm using object to represent a complex type having a property 'Id'.

I'm looking for all items in A having objects that exist in B (using Id), *but under a different key*. It's basically to tell if an object has moved keys. A is the new dictionary and B is the old.

Is there a reasonable way to accomplish this using LINQ? I would like the result to be a dictionary of all key-value pairs in A meeting the criteria. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide an example and the code you tried so far

Comment: Do you just want the objects that moved, or the entire list from `A` if any of the objects moved?

Comment: Try solving without LINQ  then convert it to LINQ. This approach is easier and better to understand.


BTW,  LINQ only makes it smaller in writing but does not help in performance. If any, sometimes it might make it even slower because of dynamic expression trees.

Comment: "I'm looking for all items in A having objects that exist in B (using Id), but under a different key. It's basically to tell if an object has moved keys" can you please explain that better and provide us an example?

Comment: Looking for objects that exist in both dictionaries (if you were to flatten their values), but are associated with different keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Interface IHasId for use Id propert:

```
public interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

And class AAA that inherited the interface:

```
public class AAA: IHasId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here the linq you look for:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IHasId>> A = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IHasId>>();
A.Add("111", new List<IHasId> { new AAA { Id = 1 }, new AAA { Id = 2 } });
A.Add("333", new List<IHasId> { new AAA { Id = 3 } });
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IHasId>> B = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IHasId>>();
B.Add("111", new List<IHasId> { new AAA { Id = 1 }});
B.Add("222", new List<IHasId> { new AAA { Id = 2 }});
B.Add("333", new List<IHasId> { new AAA { Id = 3 } });

var res = A.Where(a => a.Value.Any(c => B.Any(v => v.Value
           .Select(x => x.Id).Contains(c.Id) && a.Key != v.Key))).ToList();
```

In this example it return key 111 that has the object with Id = 2 that moved from key 222 to key 111

If you want the result as dictionary you can change the ToList with ToDictionary:

```
var res = A.Where(a => a.Value.Any(c => B.Any(v => v.Value
           .Select(x => x.Id).Contains(c.Id) && a.Key != v.Key)))
           .ToDictionary(a=>a.Key, a=>a.Value);
```

If you want in the new dictionary only the values that has change, like in the example key 111 and value with only the object with Id = 2, you can do it like this:

```
var res = A.Select(a => new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<IHasId>>(a.Key, 
           a.Value.Where(c => B.Any(v => v.Value.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(c.Id) && a.Key != v.Key))))
           .Where(a=>a.Value.Count() > 0)
           .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
```

Comment: I change the code to return List of KeyValuePair, if you don't want it as list remove th e ToList() in the end.

Comment: For the future this the previous linq that return the objects that moved: `var res = A.SelectMany(a => a.Value.Where(c => B.Any(v => v.Value.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(c.Id) && a.Key != v.Key))).ToList();`

Answer (score 3):

In terms of searchability, your dictionary has it backwards; it is efficient for looking up an object given a string, but you need to be able to look up the strings for a given object. An efficient data structure for this purpose would be a `Lookup<object,string>`.

First, use [ToLookup()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.8) to create a lookup table where the key is the object and the value is the list of keys in both list A and B. Use `Union` (instead of `Concat`) to eliminate duplicates.

```
var lookup = listA
    .Union( listB )
    .ToLookup( pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key );
```

Once you have the lookup, the problem is trivial.

```
var results = lookup.Where( x => x.Count() > 1);
```

See [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/adBo35) for a working example with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If you need A entries with original objects, it could be:

```cs
var result = A.Where(a => B.Any(b => b.Key != a.Key && b.Value.Intersect(a.Value).Any()));
```

If you need A entries with only matching objects from B, it could be:

```cs
var result = A.Select(a => new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<object>>(a.Key, B.Where(b => b.Key != a.Key).SelectMany(b => b.Value.Intersect(a.Value)))).Where(x => x.Value.Any());
```

You can provide a custom equality comparer for `Intersect` to match items by Id or whatever.

Use `new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>(result)` if you need it as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Join operator (see [join clause (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)):

```
var dictionary = (        
        from a in (from entry in A from Value in entry.Value select new { entry.Key, Value }) 
        join b in (from entry in B from Value in entry.Value select new { entry.Key, Value }) 
        on ((dynamic)a.Value).Id equals ((dynamic)b.Value).Id
        where a.Key != b.Key 
        select a
    ).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
```

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't seem to take into account that the dictionary value is an IEnumerable.

Comment: @tmaurst I had overlooked that. I corrected the answer to take that into account. I confirmed that it works when both A and B are ```Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>```